# How to identify ID of Labels in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have created 9 JLabels by array. And it has common Event Listener with method of mouseClicked(MouseEvent src){... }, here i am finding problem is, how can I identify which JLabel is clicked?

Say, if label[0] is clicked then I want to show "Label-0 is clicked",
if label[1] is clicked then I want to show "Label-1 is clicked"

Can I perform this? if yes then How?

NOTE :- I found some answer stating that add Custom 'id' Property, I would but first, I prefer if there is any default method exist.

Comment: Why dont you just compare the MouseEvent source to each JLabel until it returns true?

Comment: yeah, that's simple but effective( I don't know why this solution didn't come in my mind???)

Answer (score 3):

**Add Label**

```
 JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
 dd.add(pnl);
 addlistener();
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pnl.add(lbl[i] = new JLabel("" + i));
        lbl[i].addMouseListener(listern);

 }
```

**Listener**

```
public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent me) {
                System.err.println("Hi");
                me.getComponent();
                if(me.getSource() instanceof JLabel){
                    System.out.println("lable"+ ((JLabel)me.getSource()).getText());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for giving Answer, i don't have any use of text of JLabel, actually I want to identify that object and perform some action accordingly that object. And As I know, your answer will give "lable + Text of Label"

Answer (score 2):

You could loop the array comparing the source of the event to each element in the array...

```
for (int index = 0; index < myLabelArray.length; index++) {
    if (myLabelArray[index].equals(src.getSource())) {
        System.out.println("Label-" + index + " was clicked");
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you could "name" each label...

```
JLabel[] myLabelArray = new JLabel[9];
for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("...");
    label.setName(Integer.toString(index));
    label.addMouseListener(commonMouseListener);
    myLabelArray[index] = label;
}
```

Then in your mouse listener...

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("Label-" + ((JLabel)evt.getSource()).getName() + " was clicked");
}
```

Or you could use a `Map` instead of an array or a `List`...

Comment: Hi, this is looking me some interesting, So finally, there no default way to get Object name, is it?

Comment: `f (myLabelArray.equals(src.getSource())) {`  DYM `f (myLabelArray[index].equals(src.getSource())) {`?  I'd use a for-each loop here, much nicer.

Comment: @andrew +1 nice spot cheers. It's being a long day of blindly obvious, simply mistakes...and that's just my code :P

Comment: @hakoo it depend on what means by object name.  If the objects are already in array, they don't really have a name per same (no object really has a name, they simply have a reference)